# invalid conversion from ‘QEvent*’ to ‘QPaintEvent*’

Tags: qt, events, qt4, qpainter, touch-event

trying to find if touch event occurs or else just paint them.

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
            case QEvent::TouchBegin:
            case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            case QEvent::TouchEnd: 
        {

            QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast(event);

            if (touchEvent->touchPoints().count() == 2) 
            {
                const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint &touchPoint1 = touchEvent->touchPoints().first();
                const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint &touchPoint2 = touchEvent->touchPoints().last();
                nx=touchPoint1.scenePos().x();
                ny=touchPoint1.scenePos().y();
                pix = QPixmap::grabWidget (this,nx,ny,1,1);
                img = pix.toImage();
                rgb = img.pixel(0,0);
                color.setRgb(rgb);
                drawBit=1;
            }
        break;
         }

            case QEvent::Paint:

                  return MyWidget::paintEvent( event);  
              break;

         default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

     return true;
}



void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

time_counter++;
for(i=0;(ired,b[i]->green,b[i]->blue,255), Qt::SolidPattern));
painter.drawEllipse(b[i]->x,b[i]->y,b[i]->w, b[i]->w);
painter.drawLine(b[i]->x+b[i]->w/2,b[i]->y+b[i]->w,b[i]->x+b[i]->w/2,b[i]->y+2*b[i]->w);

if(b[i]->ballDead==false)
b[i]->y+=b[i]->vy;

if(drawBit==1 && b[i]->red==color.red() && b[i]->green==color.green() && b[i]->blue==color.blue())
ballHit(i);


}
}
```

```
this code shows error like:
mywidget.cpp:116:47: error: invalid conversion from ‘QEvent*’ to ‘QPaintEvent*’
mywidget.cpp:116:47: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘virtual void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)’
mywidget.cpp:116:47: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot include <QEvent>?

Comment: And you cannot write `return MyWidget::paintEvent( event);` because it return `void` instead `bool`.

Comment: You probably want to just handle the touch event, then return the parent handler's result for the rest: `return QWidget::event( event );`  This will handle *all* of the other event types properly.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call `paintEvent`, you'll need to cast the `QEvent*`, something like:

```
paintEvent(static_cast<QPaintEvent*>(event));
return true;
```

But as others have said, don't come complaining if you find yourself in an endless repaint loop or with an otherwise stuck event loop.

If you want a periodic repaint, set up a `QTimer` and have it call you widget's `update()` slot.

Answer (score 3):

Its not a good practice to call paintEvent() directly.Call `repaint()` or `update()` instead.Those methods will then call `paintEvent()` with the right parameter.

Comment: But again it'll be collected by MyWidget::event(). it collects all events rite. so somehow i should call paintEvent()

Comment: You are not supposed to do anything .. just don't handle the QEvent::Paint case in your `event()` method.  When you call repaint/ update the paintEvent method will be called.

Comment: i tried calling in the event function but it dint work. Where should i call it

Comment: you can call it from anywhere , just not in the paintEvent() or event() methods.

Comment: i'm already using timer to call update every 25 ms, but all events will be absorbed by MyWidget::event() rite...

Comment: No , QPaintEvent is not absorbed by any other method to my knowledge, it is only delivered only to the paintEvent() method.

Comment: Why won't "fallback" into base implementation of event? Just call BaseClass (QWidget?)::event(event); instead handling all events on your own